# Ubuntu 16.10 and USB disk corruption

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, usb, ext4, raid

This I used as a server and has a RAID 1 mdadm SATA disks. The RAID array is OK.

I backup the RAID array to a USB disk. It has been like this for years.

I tried to run a backup and mounted the USB disk and it came back:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so.
```

I did this which implies the filesystem is now bigger than the disk.

```
EXT4-fs (sdd1): bad geometry: block count 244190390 exceeds size of device (244190389 blocks)
```

I've also done

```
leigh@MINT-Server:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 931.5 GiB, 1000204883968 bytes, 1953525164 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe16dffc6

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 1953525167 1953523120 931.5G 83 Linux
```

So it's one partition spanning across the full disk. 
`fsck` has been used about once a week for many years on this disk
with no warning or hint of trouble.

How has the disk (or filesystem?) managed to expand
beyond the capacity of the disk, and can it be fixed? 
The disk could be knackered but I'm not convinced and the USB caddy has been changed.

Comment: Might be Hard- or Software-related (firmware, USB-Bridge or whatever). Did you change something? You're using Ubuntu? Your prompt tells otherwise ;-)

Comment: If it is a Linux Mint the problem/solution should be more or less the same. Mint 18 is based on Ubuntu 16.04 and as long as you stay in the shell they are extremely similar. @Leigh Bowden: (None the less, Mint it is still a bad choice for a server. It's a really good distribution, but it's designed for desktops)

Comment: Although it looks like a software problem, a quick hardware check doesn't hurt. See what happens when you connect the disk to a another system and also see what happens when you connect another drive/stick to the original system.